# Give access to internal object but prevent external modifications?

Tags: javascript, node.js

This has been bugging me for a while. I'm trying to think of the best way to design an API that can give you access to data the user will need, but is based off some internal object that the rest of the API depends on. Here's a simple example

```
function Person(name, ...) {
    this.name = name;
    this._friends = [];
    ...
}

Person.prototype.addFriend = function(friend){
    this._friends.push(friend);
};

var bob = new Person("Bob", ...);
var alice = new Person("Alice", ...);
var tut = new Person("Tutankhamun", ...);
bob.addFriend(alice);
bob.addFriend(tut);
```

(I understand prefixing "private" variables with _ doesn't really make it hidden from the public. But I prefer to use prototypes instead of redefining functions inside the constructor all the time. As far as I know, you can't use Douglas Crockford style private variables with prototypes. I think that is a different issue, anyway.)

Now lets say we want to expose a way for API users to see who is Bob's friend. The easiest way would be to just return the friends array:

```
Person.prototype.getFriends = function() {
    return this._friends;
};
```

But what if some rogue developer decides to do this?

```
bob.getFriends().pop();
```

Oh dear, poor Tutankhamun. What a terrible misunderstanding! Bob still likes Tutankhamun! The only way I can think of to fix this is to just clone the friends object every time like so:

```
Person.prototype.getFriends = function() {
    return this._friends.slice(0);
};
```

But then you have to clone it EVERY time. With large objects, that may be a problem.

So is there a better way to design this API to allow access to internal data without allowing modifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you're correct that there's a *potential* [tradeoff](http://michaelrbernste.in/2013/11/13/the-only-sure-thing-in-computer-science.html) of reduced performance when cloning an object, it's by far the most straight forward & least complex solution.

Find a [nice implementation](http://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep) for deep-cloning an object, and apply on return.

```
Person.prototype.getFriends = function() {
    return _.cloneDeep(this._friends);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze) which prevents new properties from being added; prevents existing properties from being removed; and prevents existing properties, or their enumerability, configurability, or writability, from being changed.

Comment: [object.seal()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) might be a better candidate, as he may still want to modify the existing properties but prevent add/removing ones.

Comment: You can't modify an object internally if you freeze it. Seal prevents you from adding friends in this example, which is a valid public method.

Answer (score 0):

I think your prototype should have been:

```
Person.prototype.addFriend = function(friend){
    this._friends.push(friend);
};
```

and since `_friends` is a public property, a rogue developer can still do:

```
delete bob._friends;
```

or mess with `_friends` in many other ways. Even if you emulate a private `_friends` member, someone can still overwrite the *getFriends* method.

The bottom line is that javascript has no security at all, any attempt at providing it by emulating private members is doomed (there are other reasons for private members, they are still handy). At some point you must expose an API that can be modified.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the public visibility of _friends. I want to make sure that the return value of getFriends doesn't get modified by accident, or at least indicate that it shouldn't be.

Comment: In that case you have to rely on documenting that the returned array is **the** friends array, and perhaps provide a *getFriendsCopy* method that returns a copy. Or provide methods to do everything that anyone might want to do with *_friends* so they don't modify it directly (getters/setters).

Answer (score 0):

You can put your entire class in a closure like this.

```
var Person = (function() {
  // this is your 'protected scope'
  var friends = {};
  var name = '';

  function Person(name, ...) {
    this.name = name;
    friends[name] = [];
  };

  Person.prototype.addFriend = function(friend){
    friends[this.name].push(friend);
  };

  return Person;
})();
```

This much will prevent someone from accessing it in the fashion of `person._friends.pop()` but you will still have to clone the object to return the entire Array.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, I rushed this a bit. But that case can be taken into account.

Comment: It looks like Rahat is worried that public available methods return objects that should not be modified. There is no naming convention that indicates the returned value of getFriends should not be modified. Maybe JSDoc can help out a bit but the only way to enforce it is to return a copy of the object.

Comment: Now your code leaks, when a Person instance goes out of scope the friends array doesn't follow and is never garbage collected. It also depends on name of all Persons being unique. You can help that by implementing an id but still leaks. I think it's best to stay away from patterns that simulate something that's only there to prevent careless people from making mistakes. In my opinion the down sides do not outway the up sides

Comment: HMR is exactly correct. I don't care so much about visibility than users accidentally modifying return values of public methods.